# Python, Dictionary/List Searching

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I currently have the following datasets provided from:

```
x = list((object[u'Field'] for object in y))
```

My question is I want to extract the region Value, however this changes depending on where the, `*u'@selected': u'true'*` value is.

I would like to return in a variable for the first `one = EMEA`
And the second `one = Americas`

So I can search for the `*u'@selected': u'true'*` and put the following `'Value'` into a variable, is this possible?

```
[{u'Option': [{u'@viewOrder': u'1', u'@id': u'291277', u'Value': u'Americas'}, {u'@selected': u'true', u'@viewOrder': u'2', u'@id': u'291278', u'Value': u'EMEA'}, {u'@viewOrder': u'3', u'@id': u'291279', u'Value': u'APAC'}, {u'@viewOrder': u'4', u'@id': u'292560', u'Value': u'Middle East'}], u'@required': u'false', u'@editable': u'true', u'@multi-value': u'false', u'@field-type': u'dropdown', u'@data-type': u'option', u'@display-name': u'Region', u'@id': u'127596'}], 


[{u'Option': [{u'@selected': u'true', u'@viewOrder': u'1', u'@id': u'291277', u'Value': u'Americas'}, {u'@viewOrder': u'2', u'@id': u'291278', u'Value': u'EMEA'}, {u'@viewOrder': u'3', u'@id': u'291279', u'Value': u'APAC'}, {u'@viewOrder': u'4', u'@id': u'292560', u'Value': u'Middle East'}], u'@required': u'false', u'@editable': u'true', u'@multi-value': u'false', u'@field-type': u'dropdown', u'@data-type': u'option', u'@display-name': u'Region', u'@id': u'127596'}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your data:

```
data = [[{u'Option': [{u'@viewOrder': u'1', u'@id': u'291277', u'Value': u'Americas'},
                   {u'@selected': u'true', u'@viewOrder': u'2', u'@id': u'291278', u'Value': u'EMEA'},
                   {u'@viewOrder': u'3', u'@id': u'291279', u'Value': u'APAC'}, 
                   {u'@viewOrder': u'4', u'@id': u'292560', u'Value': u'Middle East'}],
       u'@required': u'false', u'@editable': u'true', u'@multi-value': u'false', 
       u'@field-type': u'dropdown', u'@data-type': u'option', u'@display-name': u'Region', u'@id': u'127596'}],


 [{u'Option': [{u'@selected': u'true', u'@viewOrder': u'1', u'@id': u'291277', u'Value': u'Americas'}, 
                   {u'@viewOrder': u'2', u'@id': u'291278', u'Value': u'EMEA'}, 
                   {u'@viewOrder': u'3', u'@id': u'291279', u'Value': u'APAC'},
                   {u'@viewOrder': u'4', u'@id': u'292560', u'Value': u'Middle East'}], 
       u'@required': u'false', u'@editable': u'true', u'@multi-value': u'false', 
       u'@field-type': u'dropdown', u'@data-type': u'option', u'@display-name': u'Region', u'@id': u'127596'}] 
      ]
```

Some looping and indexing would extract the desired values:

```
res = []
for entry in data:
    for sub_entry in entry[0]['Option']:
        if '@selected' in sub_entry:
            res.append(sub_entry['Value'])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['EMEA', 'Americas']
```

Comment: Working, Thank you so much! :)